# How to make Xrandr permanent?

Tags: xrandr

I have a second monitor which was getting a low resolution at start up. Using xandr I am able to add the proper resolution (1360x768). How do I make it permanent? I saw another post about this, but it wasn't exactly the same.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

I use a startup script with help of ARANDR (http://www.ubuntugeek.com/arandr-a-simple-visual-front-end-for-xrandr.html) which I wrote about here: https://askubuntu.com/a/269547/2692